# API response not getting in cypress

Tags: cypress

```
///<reference types = "cypress"/>

describe('API Test Suite', ()=>{

    it('Send GET Request',()=>{

    cy.request('http://ptsv2.com/t/fu807-1554722621/post').then((res)=>{
        expect(res.body).has.property('username', 'automate')
    })
    })
})
```

I'm trying to validate username field but its throwing error

**expected '{\r\n "username": "automate",\r\n  "password": "everything",\r\n  "targetUrl": "http://ptsv2.com/t/7ty82-1554722743/post"\r\n}' to have property 'username'**

SAMPLE RESULT on POSTMAN:
{
"username": "automate",
"password": "everything",
"targetUrl": "http://ptsv2.com/t/7ty82-1554722743/post"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body` property needs parsing - true, but there are less hacky ways of doing it

```js
cy.request('GET', 'http://ptsv2.com/t/fu807-1554722621/post')
  .its('body')
  .then(JSON.parse)
  .should('have.property', 'username', 'automate')
```

or

```js
cy.request('GET', 'http://ptsv2.com/t/fu807-1554722621/post')
  .then(res => JSON.parse(res.body))
  .should('have.property', 'username', 'automate')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
///<reference types = "cypress"/>

describe('API Test Suite', () => {
  it('Send GET Request', () => {
    cy.request('GET', 'http://ptsv2.com/t/fu807-1554722621/post').then(
      (res) => {
        const user = 'automate'
        cy.wrap(res.body).should('contain', `"username": "${user}"`)
      }
    )
  })
})
```

On, digging deeper into your response body, I could see that there are empty spaces and because of which it was failing. So before asserting you have to remove the empty spacing and then apply the `has.property` assertion.

```js
///<reference types = "cypress"/>

describe('API Test Suite', () => {
  it('Send GET Request', () => {
    cy.request('GET', 'http://ptsv2.com/t/fu807-1554722621/post').then(
      (res) => {
        expect(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(res.body)))).has.property(
          'username',
          'automate'
        )
      }
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: in this case it says "expected undefined to equal 'automate'"

Comment: Can you do `cy.log(res)` and `cy.log(res.body)` before expect statement and tell me what you get?

Comment: cy.log(res) = log Object{8}

cy.log(res.body) = log{ "username": "automate", "password": "everything", "targetUrl": "http://ptsv2.com/t/7ty82-1554722743/post" }

Comment: And `cy.log(res.body.username)` ?

Comment: ```cy.log(res.body.username)```  = log

Comment: and if username needs to be saved in a variable. what should be done for it?

Comment: But thats like harcoding the response... username value will not be same everytime. Need to fetch from API response

Comment: thanks @alapan. but its still same hardcoding. how do I get username data.
like its value res.body.username something like this like this

Comment: I actually tried that locally, but it's not working for me at least. And also your code is correct. So this was an alternative I could come up with, which was working.

Comment: Hey I got the issue and updated the answer with what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll try and get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246910/discussion-between-saad-ahmed-khan-and-alapan-das).

Answer (score 1):

cy.request yields the `response` as an object so you can access it using `.its()`

```js
cy.request('your-request-url')
  .its('response.body')
  .should('have.property', 'username','automate')
```

Alternatively, you can use cy-spok to check for properties and values in a more readable code format.

```js
const 'spoke = require('cy-spok')

// in your test
cy.request('your-request-url')
  .its('response.body')
  .should(spok({
    username: 'automated',
    password: 'everything',
    //other props
    })
  )
```